# What are the weaknesses of software RAID1 in Windows 7 and Windows 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, software-raid, diskmanagement

I want to migrate current data from simple hard disk drives to RAID1 to reduce the risk of losing daily data in case of hard disk failure. Every PC I want to migrate have a RAID1 support, requiring to use BIOS.

Now, I see that there is a feature in Disk Management "Add Mirror" and "New mirrored volume", which enables *software RAID1*.

I suppose that hardware RAID1 is better than software RAID1 in terms of performance: the first one will *probably* increase *read* performance in some circumstances, whereas the second one will *probably* do nothing. Is it true?

What are the other drawbacks, problems and weaknesses of software vs. hardware RAID1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows specifically we've discovered that you can't extend software-Raid1 volumes. This is more of an issue when you've got some kind of storage array backing your server, but can also arise when adding new disks to a server. Once that RAID1 volume is created, that's the size it shall be forever more.

Comment: Well, since I don't expect any hardware changes (other than replacing the whole machine), it's ok for me.